# Error when trying to compile with make file

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

``I get an error when I try to my application with a make file. This is my first attempt at creating a make file myself and i found many examples online, but i cannot get mine to work. The error i get, however is a compile error, that what i compile manually, i do not get. The error is:

```
`dave@ubuntu:~/School/CS647/Programs/Homework4$ make
g++ -Wall -o StatWrapper StatWrapper.o tools.o
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [StatWrapper] Error 1
```

`
Here is my make file:

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -Wall
UTILDIR = ../../Utilities/
OBJECTS =  Sweeper.o FileID.o P4Ford.o DirentWrapper.o StatWrapper.o tools.o

all: StatWrapper DirentWrapper FileID Sweeper P4Ford

#P4Ford: $(OBJECTS)
#   $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o P4Ford

DirentWrapper: DirentWrapper.o tools.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o DirentWrapper DirentWrapper.o tools.o

StatWrapper: StatWrapper.o tools.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o StatWrapper StatWrapper.o tools.o

P4Ford: P4Ford.o Sweeper.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o P4Ford P4Ford.o Sweeper.o

Sweeper: Sweeper.o FileID.o StatWrapper.o DirentWrapper.o tools.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o Sweeper Sweeper.o FileID.o StatWrapper.o DirentWrapper.o tools.o

FileID: FileID.o tools.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o FileID FileID.o tools.o

#tools: tools.o
#   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(UTILDIR)tools.cpp

# dependencies ---------------------------------------------------
DirentWrapper.o: $(UTILDIR)DirentWrapper.cpp  $(UTILDIR)DirentWrapper.hpp
StatWrapper.o: $(UTILDIR)StatWrapper.cpp  $(UTILDIR)StatWrapper.hpp
P4Ford.o: P4Ford.cpp  Sweeper.hpp
Sweeper.o: Sweeper.cpp  FileID.hpp
FileID.o: FileID.cpp  $(UTILDIR)tools.hpp
tools.o: $(UTILDIR)tools.cpp $(UTILDIR)tools.hpp

# cleanup
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJECTS)
```

I believe this is an issue with my make file because it works when i compile manually, but i can't be sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is where we ask if you're completely certain that your .o file has a `main()`.

Comment: How do you compile those files manually? Post the full output of `make` (after `make clean`).

Comment: I'm not sure that you're reading what `make` is doing then...

Comment: `dave@ubuntu:~/School/CS647/Programs/Homework4$ g++ -Wall -o P4Ford *.cpp
dave@ubuntu:~/School/CS647/Programs/Homework4$ `

Comment: Also, I posted up the wrong make file, all the files are in the same directory so the make file im working with does not use the $(UTILDIR). It will eventually need to use that, but i wanted to get it to work first.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams i am not sure exactly what its doing.

Comment: @DFord: I think Ignacio’s point is that `make` _tells you_ exactly what it is doing; you need to identify the difference between that and what you want it to do...

Comment: @BrianNixon got it. i just need to figure out how to do what i want to do with a makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `-c` to the rules building object files. Without this the compiler assumes you are creating an executable which requires `main()` to be defined. The `-c` flag indicates the no linking shall be done, yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
StatWrapper: StatWrapper.o tools.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o StatWrapper StatWrapper.o tools.o
```

In this rule you are linking `StatWrapper.o` and `tools.o` and creating executable `StatWrapper`. This won't work, because neither of them has a `main` function.

You need to remove all those invalid rules and leave just one, which will combine all object files into one executable.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with an object file. Make has a built-in rule for compiling `.cpp` files, but to be on the safe side (and for practice) we'll write a rule:

```
Sweeper.o: Sweeper.cpp FileID.hpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c Sweeper.cpp -o Sweeper.o
```

**Test this before you go any farther.**

we see some redundancy in that rule, so we'll use [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) to clean it up a little:

```
Sweeper.o: Sweeper.cpp FileID.hpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

**Test this before you go any farther.**

Notice that the command doesn't mention `Sweeper` explicitly. When we write the rules for the other object files they'll all have the same command. So we can gather them up in a [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
OBJECTS =  Sweeper.o FileID.o P4Ford.o DirentWrapper.o StatWrapper.o tools.o

DirentWrapper.o: $(UTILDIR)DirentWrapper.cpp  $(UTILDIR)DirentWrapper.hpp
StatWrapper.o: $(UTILDIR)StatWrapper.cpp  $(UTILDIR)StatWrapper.hpp
P4Ford.o: P4Ford.cpp  Sweeper.hpp
Sweeper.o: Sweeper.cpp  FileID.hpp
FileID.o: FileID.cpp  $(UTILDIR)tools.hpp
tools.o: $(UTILDIR)tools.cpp $(UTILDIR)tools.hpp

$(OBJECTS) : %.o: %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Now you should be able to, e.g., `make FileID.o`.

**Test this before you go any farther.**

Now that Make knows how to build the objects, we just need one rule to link them into the executable:

```
P4Ford: P4Ford.o Sweeper.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@
```

If you make this the first rule, Make will treat it as the default. (And are you sure that `P4Ford` needs only those two object files? Maybe it should be `P4Ford: $(OBJECTS)`.)